# i dont know why when i change my operation variable inside the function when called into the event listener it doesnt change globally

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, calculator

i am new to javascript and i want to build a calculator but when i try to change the global variable `operator` in the event listener the `operator` variable changes only locally but when i need the variable in the event listener linked to equal button it takes the initial value of the operator which is empty so i cant choose the opertaor and do my calculations

```js
let current_number = "";
let operator = "";
let previous = "";
let disp = document.querySelector("#current");
let prev = document.querySelector("#previous");
let equal = document.querySelector("#equal");

equal.addEventListener("click", calculate);

let number = document.querySelectorAll(".digit");
let oper = document.querySelectorAll(".operation");
number.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
    disp.textContent = current_number;
  });
});

oper.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    handleOperator(e.target.textContent);
    prev.textContent = previous + " " + operator;
    disp.textContent = current_number;
  });
});

function handleNumber(num) {
  if (current_number.length < 10) {
    current_number += num;
  }
}

function handleOperator(op) {
  operator = op;
  previous = current_number;
  current_number = "";
}

function calculate() {
  previous = Number(previous);
  current_number = Number(current_number);
  if (operator === "+") {
    previous += current_number;
  } else if (operator === "-") {
    previous -= current_number;
  } else if (operator === "*") {
    previous *= current_number;
  } else {
    previous /= current_number;
  }
  console.log(previous);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2a92c7, #00ffc6);
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
}
#current {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
#display {
  background-color: rgba(13, 42, 6, 0.7);
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #9ea0a2;
}
.digit {
  font: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div
        class="row text-light align-items-center justify-content-center"
        style="min-height: 100vh"
      >
        <div id="display" class="col-sm-5 col-xl-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="main" class="col-12 bg-gradient">
              <div id="previous" class="col"></div>
              <div id="current" class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="col-6 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">AC</button>
            <button class="col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">Del</button>
            <button class="operation col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">
              /
            </button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">1</button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">2</button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">3</button>
            <button class="col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none operation">
              *
            </button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">4</button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">5</button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">6</button>
            <button class="col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none operation">
              -
            </button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">7</button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">8</button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">9</button>
            <button class="col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none operation">
              +
            </button>
            <button
              id="dicim"
              class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none"
            >
              .
            </button>
            <button class="digit col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">0</button>
            <button id="equal" class="col-6 btn btn-secondary shadow-none">
              =
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I've converted your code to a stack snippet. Please add the HTML.

Comment: i added my html

Comment: Use `e.target.textContent.trim()` to remove all the whitespace around the operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug you would see what is happening

```
function handleOperator(op) {
  console.log('handleOperator', operator, op);
  operator = op;
```

You will see that your `op` has a bunch of whitespace in it.

trim it

```
operator = op.trim();
```

or better yet use data attributes

```
<button class="col-3 btn btn-secondary shadow-none operation" data-value="*">*</button>
```

and reading it

```
handleOperator(e.currentTarget.dataset.value);
```

Comment: thank you very much i solved the problem i finde out that pretier in my vsocde add white spaces when i press save